# Passing Python Object Into Rust

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I am trying to pass a Python object into rust and perform operations using the fields of the Python object.

Python:

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3

b = myclass()
print(b.a)
// 3
```

Rust:

```
#[pyfn(m, "rust_obj")]
fn rust_obj_py(py: Python, x: PyObject) -> PyResult<PyObject> { 
    let y = x.clone_ref(py);
    y.a += 2;
    Ok(y)
}
```

Expected result when calling from Python would be:

```
c = rust_obj(b)
print(c.a)
// 5
```

Instead Rust error out when compiling:

```
error[E0609]: no field `a` on type `pyo3::PyObject`
   --> src\lib.rs:926:5
    |
926 |         y.a += 2;
    |           ^ unknown field
```

Is there a way to list the object fields and methods in rust and manipulate the fields?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling [`clone_ref`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.9.2/pyo3/struct.PyObject.html#method.clone_ref) on y:

```rust
let y = x.clone_ref(py);
```

`clone_ref` returns another `PyObject`. Then you're invoking

```rust
y.a += 2;
```

And the compiler correctly tells you "no field `a` on type pyo3::PyObject". Because `PyObject` doesn't expose the fields you would expect in a Python object directly (It would be difficuly to do so since python is dynamically typed whereas rust is a statically typed language, so all members of PyObject have to be known at compile-time). The documentation is helpful in these cases to learn how to use [`PyObject`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.9.2/pyo3/struct.PyObject.html). There you'll see that you can still access `a`, but you have to go through the [`getattr`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.9.2/pyo3/struct.PyObject.html#method.getattr) method. In order to do the `+=` I suspect you'd probably best call python's `__iadd__` method explicitly through the [`call_method`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.9.2/pyo3/prelude/struct.PyObject.html#method.call_method) API.